# How to implement MapTiler server in React Native app

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps, maptiler

I am building a mobile app that includes a map and some markers, I found that using react-native-maps with Google API will cost a lot.

I started hosting my own map tile server using MapTiler.

My problem is I can't find a library that can display my map in React native component.

This is my MapTiler server:
I don't know how to implement these raster tiles in my react native app.

I am using Expo.

[image]

Which library should I use that doesn't have any pricing or commercial license.
If you have a good solution please give me an example.

I tried to use react-native-maps but it didn't show any tiles.

```
        <MapView
          region={location}
          rotateEnabled={false}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          style={styles.map}
          showsUserLocation
          mapType="none"
        >
          <UrlTile
            tileSize={512}
            urlTemplate="http://localhost:3650/api/maps/satellite-hybrid/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            maximumZ={19}
          />
          <Marker
            title="Home"
            coordinate={{
              latitude: location.latitude,
              longitude: location.longitude,
            }}
          />
        </MapView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that react native doesn't understand what localhost is.
I had to change localhost into my IP address 192.168.1.1

I got it from CMD using command `ipconfig`

```
urlTemplate="http://192.168.1.1:3650/api/maps/satellite-hybrid/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please check the following article and let me know, it you find some useful info there? It targets MapTiler Cloud, but I believe some principles will be very similar to Server.

https://documentation.maptiler.com/hc/en-us/articles/4405444890897-How-to-display-MapLibre-GL-JS-map-using-React-JS